# select option isn't adding object in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to add a mongoose object to another mongoose object using a select bar in a form. All the other key,value pairs insert correctly, even the checkbox bool, but the select-option combo won't save the I've done this before with no problem, but in ionic, it doesn't seem to want to work. Is there a work around or am I just messing something up in the code?

```js
    $scope.addProperty = function(prop){
      console.log(prop);
      Props.add(prop)
        .then(function(res) {
          console.log(res.data);
          //window.location.reload();
        })
        .catch(function(error){
          console.log(error);
        });
      };
```

```html
<form method = "post" class="form-inline" role="form" action = "localhost:3000/managers/newApt">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" >Tenants:</label>
    <select ng-model="prop.tenants" class="column medium-3" ng-options="manager.name for manager in allManagers">    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only">Address</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model='prop.address'>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click='addProperty(prop)'>Add Property</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this video tutorial they use `var controllerName = this`, inside controller and reference methods and properties of the controller through var `controllerName`, for example this is a controller:

```
angular

  .module('your-app-module')
  .controller('ExampleController', function ($scope, $state) {

    //This var is to bind methods and vars in view(html) to this specific controller
    var ExmpleCtrl = this; //this is the var that is going to replace $scope


    //NOTICE no $scope but rather ExmpleCtrl 
    ExmpleCtrl.goToState = function (state) { 
      $state.go(state);
    };
  });
```

Now in your html try:

```
    <ion-view ng-controller="ExampleController as exmpleCtrl">
      <ion-content>
<!-- notice how I use exmpleCtrl instead of $scope to access controller or to pass info -->
        <div ng-click="exmpleCtrl.doSomething()">
    </ion-view>
```

If you still have doubt check this short video (ignore it's for webstorm the way they bind the controller to the a variable inside controller referenced to this is what is useful): http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/03/angularjs-workflow-in-webstorm/